# Saleor Product Bulk upload script

Tags: django, python-3.x, saleor

I am new to saleor and is creating a ecommerce platform. I have downloaded saleor and made it up and running. I have 1000+ products to add. To add manually is a big nightmare. Checking if there is any scripts or ways to bulk upload products along with details (like images etc) to the saleor

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Im at a similar crossroad as you were a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Saleor has GraphQL API that can be used for that purpose.

Here's brief documentation:
https://docs.getsaleor.com/en/latest/architecture/graphql.html

Queries you'll be most interested in lives in
https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/saleor/graphql/product/mutations/products.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use its GraphQL API, it requires about 5 queries to import a product to Saleor properly. There is no official guide for tasks like this but you can look at its [API reference](https://docs.saleor.io/docs/3.x/developer/api-reference/) document, trying different mutations based on product structure. Once you get it done with GraphQL playground you can write a script to import all your products.