# Saleor e-commerce: How to batch insert products through python code or API

Tags: python, django, graphql, e-commerce, saleor

I am trying to do some tests on saleor e-commerce cms by adding some products automatically from some cvs file through python
Unfotunately I have only found some examples GraphQL API for reading the existing products from the database [Saleor Product Bulk upload script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435400/saleor-product-bulk-upload-script) but I can not find nothing for add a product with GraphQL API. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> With the `DEBUG=True` setting enabled, Saleor exposes an interactive GraphQL editor under `/graphql`, that allows accessing the API from the browser.

<del>Probably (99,9%) error in documentation: should be `/graphiql` (vs `/graphql` - pointing to API)</del>  When enabled shows in browser `"graphql-playground-react"`  -  'industry standard' (modified well known `graphiql`) tool for trying queries, exploring types, available mutations etc.

Browse for (or just start typing) 'mutation ProductCreate {`. This is a single product method you can use for building a batch update.

Try your mutations in playground (using variables - check graphiql docs), then from code.

Comment: No, the route is `/graphql/`only - https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/saleor/urls.py#L27

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r you're right - it's on the same url (updated answer) - IMHO main problem is lacking docs, no mutations examples - batch/bulk is a minor one

Answer (score 0):

The pytest fixtures give a good brief on how to create products in a programmatic way inside python - https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/tests/conftest.py#L389

Also, I don't think the bulk APIs exist for *adding* products. From the code I can see that they're meant for deletion & stuff (managing) - https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/saleor/graphql/product/bulk_mutations/products.py

Comment: `Product.objects.bulk_create` at #L467 ;)

Comment: Thanks, but that's just Django's `bulk_create` method, not sure if it creates the necessary variants automatically.

Comment: Probably not but can be usable for simple products (w/o variants).